# Updating a column only if it's null -- Inside a replace into statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to `update`, or `create` a new row in my table. I'm using a `replace into` query.

For one of the columns, I need to update it only if it is null, and otherwise leave it as is. This is what I tried:

```
replace into table name (..some columns..) values (..some values.. , 

IF(creation_time is null, STR_TO_DATE('2017/02/21 18:25:51', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '')
```

but this doesn't work. I also tried plugging this code into the `replace into`:

```
SET creation_time = CASE
   WHEN creation_time is null THEN STR_TO_DATE('2022-02-20 15:40:58', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
   ELSE NULL
END
```

but this doesn't work either. Any solution?

Comment: What means "doesn't work"? In your second query you're overwriting the values with NULL if they're not NULL, is that what you want to do?

Comment: The creation_time is updated even if it is not null.

Comment: Then do ELSE creation_time instead of ELSE NULL and add "WHERE creation_time is null" at the end.

Answer (score 1):

In your second snippet you're overwriting the values of creation_time with NULL if they're not NULL.
You should replace the 'ELSE NULL' with 'ELSE creation_time'.

```
SET creation_time = CASE
   WHEN creation_time is null THEN STR_TO_DATE('2022-02-20 15:40:58', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
   ELSE creation_time 
END
```

Or just use a WHERE-clause at the end:

```
SET creation_time = STR_TO_DATE('2022-02-20 15:40:58', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
WHERE creation_time IS NULL
```

Comment: Hi Toby, thanks for your valuable input. I just edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When `creation_time` is not null, you should set it by itself:

```
SET creation_time = CASE
   WHEN creation_time is null THEN STR_TO_DATE('2022-02-20 15:40:58', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
   ELSE creation_time 
END
```

Or you can just use `where`:

```
SET creation_time = STR_TO_DATE('2022-02-20 15:40:58', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
WHERE creation_time IS NULL
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error. This is the relevant snippet from my query: `...value, value, SET creation_time = STR_TO_DATE('2022-02-20 15:40:58', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
WHERE creation_time IS NULL
);`